# save() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send an email out once a field is changed. I've done my research and seen a lot of solution to similar issues but none seems to solve my problem.

It seems the issue comes from the fact that i define 'user' at the start of the save method. Any help please!

```
class CountryList(model.Models):
    score= models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank = True, choices=zip(range(1, 11), range(1, 11)))  
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null =True, blank=True)  

    def save(self, user, *args, **kwargs):  
        old_CountryList = CountryList.objects.get(pk=self.id)    
        if old_CountryList.score!= self.score: 
            send_mail('The user ' + user.username + ' has changed the Score for ' + self.country \
                  + 'from ' + str(old_CountryList.score) + ' to '                    \
                  + str(self.score) + '.\nThis change was made at '                       \
                  + str(datetime.datetime.now())[:19] + '. \n\nLink to the change: http://'         \
                  + socket.gethostname() + '/home/countries/' + str(self.id),           # email body
                  'some_email_here',                                                 # send from
                  settings.EMAIL_RECIPIENTS,                                                   # send to
                  fail_silently=False)  
        super(CountryList, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save()
```

Comment: Why are you changing the signature of `save`? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Comment: Django's built in method `Model.save` has only optional parameters. What is the reason for `user` parameter here? This will break everything, since Django believes, that `save` could be called without parameters.

Comment: Okay thanks. Where and how do I then define `user` parameter? if not includeded, it says `user` not defined.
Also doesn't work when i try to import it with `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: You can pass the `user` parameter to the `save()` anyway, and have it overridden to pop it out of `kwargs` before calling the "real one"

Comment: Thanks @mccc i think your solution would work but not exactly sure how to  pop it.
I tried   `self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None) `

Comment: Yes that should work: you have to pass it to the `save()` method as a named argument, and then call `super().save()` passing on the rest of the args.. Is it not working for you?

Comment: Apologies as I am just seeing you comment now. Yes i've done exactly what you said but it doesn't seem to work. It still shows the same error. It does not pop the value out before calling `super().save()`

Answer (score 1):

Django's `Model` API expects that `Model.save()` sticks to the defined signature, as quite a few other parts of the framework, contribs and  third part apps rely on this.

Also sending mails from the `Model.save()` method is really a terrible idea... You have to understand that models are (and must remain) strictly decoupled from the HTTP request (views...) cycle - as they may be modified by other code too (think custom management commands etc) and you won't necessarily have a "current user" at hand (nor want to send mails to anyone).

In you case since you're obviously only concerned by changed made thru your app's views the mail should be send by the view itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please what will be the best way for me to write the above code correctly and get the right output.

Comment: Simple solution : just put the emailing code in your view - the one that handles your model's modification - instead of putting it in your model.

Comment: Apolgies for the many questions but i'm kinda a novice in django and need to get this working.

I've put the save method in the view, and also reflected it in my urls.py but the code runs but nothing happens when i run it. It seems i'm still doing something wrong. thanks

Comment: I didn't say "write a view with a copy-paste of the save method" (which wouldn't make any sense), I said "put the email sending part of your save method's code in the view that handle your model's updates".